# Fix audio crackling linux

Tags: linux, audio, bugs

I had audio crackling in 2 different software at least (Chrome & Spotify) so I guessed it was system level issue. I searched and found a solution that worked for me and wanted to share it.

Edit : Issue was on ubuntu 21.10 on latitude 5511

Comment: There are hundreds of reasons for sound crackling. As long as you do not offer a deeper analysis of the problem together with a minimum description of your configuration, any solution offered won't value more than a simple guess.

Comment: I don't know how does pulse audio works and as user of it, I don't think I will dig more this topic for now. I just found a solution to my cracking issue and as it solved my cracking issue (no more cracking !) It is enough for me. There is no obvious risk to try this solution for someone having same issue I guess. The pure user will also not dig about what really solved the issue like me, and the more advanced user having deeper knowlege of pulseaudio might understand what happened under the hoods where I cannot tell more myself. Also please consider I just want to share a solution overall.

Answer (score 3):

Found [here on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ValveIndex/comments/iavw77/does_anyone_else_have_audio_cracklingpopping_on/g1rtlx4/)

you can try to :

- Edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and set `default-sample-rate = 48000`
- Create `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf` and add `default-sample-rate = 48000`
- Run `pulseaudio -k`

It worked for me. I hope this help.

Comment: In addition to my comment in OP, you could at least explain **why** this worked for you.

Comment: It worked because I had cracking noise in my headset before, I applied this trick and I have no more cracking noise in both chrome, spotify at least. That's all.

Comment: hahah utopman has done you there @MC68020. However I am with MC, I would like to understand why this might have worked, because this does not work for me.

Comment: @JamieHutber :-) Please do open a new question (provided you first ensured that it cannot be a hadware problem, you specify the sound server in use, the applications used for playback, and inform whether the pb is reproducible or not using *aplay* on the console.). I do not know if I'll be able to answer but I make no doubt that this will be a far more profitable Q/A than this one ;-)

Answer (score -1):

had crackling sound with IVAO Aurora 1.0.28b Ubuntu 20.04.6LTS, appled

Create ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf and add default-sample-rate = 48000

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```

worked perfectly

Comment: This appears to merely duplicate utopman's answer.